# Oracle DBV File Parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

For our 10g Oracle database I had a script that would periodically create batch files to run DBVerify on all our datafiles.  This way if I needed to check for corruption I would just have to run the batch files.  After upgrading to Oracle 11g my batch files do not worked.  I traced the problem down to dbv itself.  Here is the command generated by the script:

```
dbv FILE=F:\ORACLE\ORADATA\CD\CAMPUSCHURCH1.DBF BLOCKSIZE=4096 
LOGFILE='c:\DBVerify_COREDEV\CAMPUSCHURCH1_55.txt'
```

When I run this it gives a DBV-00100: Specified FILE (C:\Windows\system32/F:\ORACLE\ORADATA\CD\CAMPUSCHURCH1.DBF) not accessible.  *Note: The folder I am in is C:\Windows\system32.*  I can get it to work by switching to F:\ and removing F:\ from my dbv call, but I don't like that because then I'd have to change my script to switch to the proper drive before each dbv call.

Can anyone verify my findings and/or provide a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems like a bug, regression from 10g... did a quick lookup in metalink and didn't find anything...
How about opening an SR with a test case of 10g vs 11g? if it is a known issue, you might get a patch. If it isn't, they will hopefully fix it (eventually).

In a bit related note, you can consider using RMAN to check for physical and logical corruptions in your database. I believe it is better and more comprehensive check. For example,run rman VALIDATE CHECK LOGICAL DATABASE  [Check the docs here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmvalid.htm). If rman find block corruption, it populates v$database_block_corruption and you can then just use rman to recover the specific corrupted blocks. You can parallelize the RMAN VALIDATE by opening multiple channels...

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I've looked at the docs and ran a few tests and that does indeed appear to do what I need and more.  I was headed toward opening a case, but if VALIDATE replaces my use for dbv I don't think I'll even bother with a case.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same on 11gR1on Windows 2008 x64!!